# Why I can't output the image in rotate?

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php 

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('simpletext.jpg');
$imgRotated = imagerotate($img, 45,-1);

imagejpeg($imgRotated,'newsimpletext.jpg',100);


?>



<img src="simpletext.jpg" />

<hr>

<img sec="newsimpletext.jpg" />
```

I want to output the image in rotate version but it has error

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\developphp\index.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

there must be an error in the path,
test this code:

```
if(is_file('simpletext.jpg')){
   $img = imagecreatefromjpeg('simpletext.jpg');
   $imgRotated = imagerotate($img, 45,-1);

   imagejpeg($imgRotated,'newsimpletext.jpg',100);
}
else echo "error on image file or path";

echo '<img src="simpletext.jpg" /><hr><img src="newsimpletext.jpg" />';
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: There is still have error on the imagejpeg :( Any solution? The image path doesn't have a problem

Comment: @JakzAizzat chack now

Comment: Still can't solve it.

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\developphp\index.php on line 7

Comment: Have test it with another image still doesn't work. Any solution?